# Creating a PVC on new cluster stuck in Pending

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a new cluster in GCE and added the following PVC to it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-logis
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce 
  volumeName: logis-data
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

But it never actually provisions the PV.  It just shows status as Pending with no events:

Here is the PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-logis
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce 
  volumeName: logis-data
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

And the describe:

```
Name:          pvc-logis
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  standard-rwo
Status:        Pending
Volume:        logis-data
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      0
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:        <none>
```

When I try to run this deployment:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: downloader-cron
spec:
  schedule:  "0 1 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: downloader
            image: us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/spry-gateway-357903/logis-docker-repository/downloader
            volumeMounts:
            - name: "logis-data-dir"
              mountPath: "/data"
          volumes:
          - name: "logis-data-dir"
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: "pvc-logis"
              readOnly: false
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I see this error:

```
The Pod’s Persistent Volume Claims are not bound to a volume. This error might happen if your Persistent Volume is not provisioned.
```

I'm basically trying to do a basic PVC setup following the documentation at [Persistent volumes and dynamic provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes) but I think I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

> volumeName: logis-data

and try again

```
kubectl get pv
kubectl get pvc
```